# when i press f12 to see my mobile design i have a space in blank on the left - CSS

Tags: html, css, flexbox, responsive-design

This is a very specific problem, when a press f12 to see the mobile style version, i have a space in blank on the right... When i press f5 it disappear and i have a totally responsive page. I would like to see a full responsive desing even when i press f12.

I had tried this

```
*{ margin: 0; 
    padding: 0;
box-sizing: border-box;}


main{
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
 }
header{
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
}
```

Comment: perhaps there is an absolute positioned element that overflows the bounds of page. If you are using a third-party plugin (As well as AOS or any animating plugin) using `overflow-x:hidden` may help in some cases.

Comment: you totally right, i have an absolute positioned element, i'll check it out.

Comment: yes, i have solved it. Thank you so much